# Spark UDFs that work on Any

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do I create a UDF to use in SQL expressions that can take in `Any` type?

Something like:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("myudf", (x: Any) => x)
```

throws `Schema for type Any is not supported`

while this works, obviously:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("myudf", (x: String) => x)
```